# dropdown menu disappears at rollup

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdown menu that all is good when it rolls down, but when it rolls up, the main menus disappear.
I also added the screenshot of the behavior as well.

HTML file:

```
 <!-- Sidebar menus -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column w-100">    
    <hr class="style-one">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown w-100">
        <a href="#equitiesSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light pl-4" id="equitiesSubmenu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
          <svg class="bi bi-currency-dollar" width="16" height="20" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="currentColor"><use xlink:href="#dollarSign"/></svg>
          Equities
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="equitiesSubmenu">
            <li><a href="{{url_for('core.simulator')}}" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Simulator</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url_for('core.portfolio')}}" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

And this is the style.css file:

```
/* for navbar */
.navbar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #212529;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.nav-link:active,
.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #c0c2c5;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #be1ca9;
}

.dropdown-item:active,
.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #a81219;
}

.sidebar {
    z-index: 0;
}

.active-nav {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

.active-cont {
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    }

/* Gradient color1 - color2 - color1 */
hr.style-one {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    }
```

And this is the screenshot of the dropdown menu at roll-down then roll-up:

[image: dropdown roll-down] [image: dropdown roll-up]

Comment: You tagged the question with bootstrap-4 but, you use a data attribute name from bootstrap-5 `data-bs-toggle` while v4 uses `data-toggle`. There are significant differences between the two, so please update the tag as necessary.

Comment: @ArleighHix I know, because there is no Bootstrap5 suggestions, that's why I tagged v4, still that's not what's making this behaviour happens